# How to auto-break a long word when auto-wrapping text

Tags: sublimetext3

I know we can use `"word_wrap": "auto"`   in the User settings to make Sublime Text 3 auto wrap text, but how can I make it break a long word when wrapping?

In a sentence like:

```
a long word aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I want it to

```
a long word aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
```

but not:

```
a long word
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

First, I saw advice to add `"auto_wrap_break_long_word" : false,` to the setting file, but it made no sense to me.

And then, I get advice from comments by using  [Sublime Wrap Plus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Wrap%20Plus)

However, it is not what I want.

The Readme of Sublime Wrap Plus says: 
`Enhanced “wrap lines” command for Sublime Text 2 or 3. This is for the manual hard line wrap command. It does not affect the automatic soft line wrapping.`

But what I want is not “**HARD line wrap**” because it will add real some line breaks and change the text file. And what I want is to break long word in “**SOFT line wrap**”(which will not change texts but only change how it looks)

In fact , I've tried to install the `Sublime Wrap Plus` package and set `"WrapPlus.break_long_words":true` in `Preferences >> Settings — User`.

But nothing changed about my SOFT line wrap.

THANKS for all advice anyway!

Comment: No no we don't want you to be sad, not used sublime for a while but check if this package can help you out https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Wrap%20Plus

Comment: Please don't bother commenting about misspelled words or changing the text of your question. We can tell they're misspelled or whether you changed it. In the case of misspelled words, most browsers have spelling check available, so enable it to get the added help. Also, grammar checkers are available for browsers, and they'll handle spelling plus most grammar issues. Comments are for us to give you feedback or to ask for more information. You should put the requested information into your question, inserting it where you would initially, without "edit" or "update", so we can easily find it.

Comment: SORRY for my misuse and THANK YOU for all your comments and guidance sincerely !!
I have tried the plugin mentioned by @George. However, it is not what I want. I saw from Readme of Sublime Wrap Plus, which says " Enhanced “wrap lines” command for Sublime Text 2 or 3. This is for the manual hard line wrap command. It does not affect the automatic soft line wrapping. " 
But what I want is not “HARD line wrap” because it will really add some line breaks and change my text, and what I want is “break long word when SOFT line wrap”(which will not change my text but only change how it looks)